# How to design mobile forms to be autofilled from contact card on mobile device

Tags: iphone, html, safari, autofill

I am designing a form for a website and everything (First name, last name, email, etc) is being autofilled from my contact card in Safari except for the city, state zip. The only thing funky about the input field is that is has some autocomplete javascript on it.

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-inp required" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-inp required"/>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-inp required email"/>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-inp required phoneUS" />
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
        <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="City/State/Zip" class="required"/>
</div>
```

Is there some naming conventions on the ID or name of the input element that causes Safari to autofill?